# Return the indexes of the elements after finding the difference in two lists

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to find the difference between two lists of strings, and return the index (in the original list) of the remaining elements in list1.

For example, if list1 contains "Orange", "Blue", "Yellow", and list2 contains "Blue", I can easily get the difference using the Except method. However, I want to return the indexes - 1 and 3 in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Pardon the laziness of the list creation:

```
var x = new[] { "Orange", "Blue", "Yellow" }.ToList();
var y = new[] { "Blue" }.ToList();

var indices = x.Except(y).Select(z => x.IndexOf(z));
```

This is not at all very efficient, but it solves the issue.  If this is actually for something useful and not just a mental exercise, I would re-evaluate why you are doing this.

Comment: why are you calling ToList ?

Comment: This scales pretty horribly if the lists are not small.

Comment: Array doesn't have an `IndexOf` method.

Comment: It's a horrible idea, but not sure of any better way strictly using Linq.

Answer (score 1):

```
list1.Select((e,idx) => new { e, idx })
.Where(x => !list2.Contains(x.e)).Select(x => x.idx);
```

Comment: Like Jaime's solution, this scales quite horribly.

Comment: You can convert `list2` to `HashSet`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ExceptBy` to perform an except based on a projection of the given items, allowing you to first project each collection into an item containing its index, and then perform the except based on the item itself:

```
var query = first.Select((index, item) => new { index, item })
    .ExceptBy(second.Select((index, item) => new { index, item }),
        pair => pair.item);
```

---

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> ExceptBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    IEnumerable<TSource> other,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
{
    comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;
    var keys = new HashSet<TKey>(other.Select(keySelector), comparer);
    foreach (var item in source)
        if (keys.Add(keySelector(item)))
            yield return item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional way to solve the problem:

```
var x = new[] { "Orange", "Blue", "Yellow" };
var y = new HashSet<string>(new[] { "Blue" });
var indices = Enumerable.Range(0, x.Length)
                        .Where(i => !y.Contains(x[i]))
                        .ToArray();
```